# Google sheets: How to write a formula that performs a sum from column_x until previous column and apply it to the rest of the columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have these two columns:
[image]
For the next columns I would to apply this formula:

```
SUM[all_previous_columns]
```

I would like to write it once for the third column and apply it for the rest of the columns.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean this?

[image]

You should use absolute addressing to first column in the range you want to sum and relative addressing to last column. Then you can drag your formula right as far as you want.

Answer (score 1):

As it just doubles each time, you could also write it as an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula((A1+B1)*2^(column(C1:1)-3))
```

[image]